# PHP Get memory usage in hosting package

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I have a **shared** hosting with many websites (PHP, MySQL).

Suddenly today some of the websites became unavailable, showing a "Not Found" and "404" error when trying to access them. Seems to be to random websites. Nothing has been changed in the hosting configuration, websites files, domains, etc... **nothing at all**.

When contacting the hosting, I'm told that the reason is because I've reached the limit of 80 MB of RAM allocated to my plan, but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me, nothing has changed internally in terms of scripts or amount of concurrent users. Besides, now that it's night hours and there's pretty much no one using those websites they're still down.

So my question is: is there any way I can get the global amount of memory that my websites are using? I know I can use phpInfo() to get maximum memory... If there's no global way, even if it's a "per website" basis that would work for now.

The idea behind this would be to maybe detect the memory usage with PHP, and if it's higher than certain value deny the access to the users, instead of letting the whole thing collapse.

All this of course if the memory usage theory is true... shouldn't I get something more specific about memory errors in that case? Of course the hosting is offering me to upgrade to a dedicated server, so that's why I don't trust much what they're telling me, maybe they just want me to get a more expensive product instead of fixing whatever is wrong in their server...

Comment: `du -Ks /path/to/your/domains`. And, _yes_ - do _not_ use shared hostings

Comment: @AlmaDo thanks, but I'm talking about RAM memory

Comment: Then it's per _script_